# How to pass the object value dynamically as parameter into new FormControl() in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown whose data is coming from loop.Here I need to get the selected value and selected text on page load and on click a span.I am using reactive form here.To make default selection I am using new FormControl(1) ,Every thing is working correct I am getting the result in console.But when I am removing first object of array from my json and reload the page its creating error,since I hardcoded to 1 in FormControl,if I change to FormControl(2) its working fine.But I need to pass it dynamically so that it can work with any number of object. Here is the code below and demo example I created https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwrvvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      name = 'Angular';
      registerForm: FormGroup;
      statusdata: any;
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
      {
          this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                 title: new FormControl(1)
         });

      }
      ngOnInit() {

          this.statusdata = [{"groupid":1,"groupname":"project1"},{"groupid":2,"groupname":"project2"},{"groupid":3,"groupname":"project3"}];
          console.log('selected Value', this.registerForm.get('title').value);
          console.log('selected name', this.statusdata.filter(v => v.groupid == this.registerForm.get('title').value)[0].groupname);
      }
     getSelectedVal(){
        console.log('selected Value', this.registerForm.get('title').value);
        console.log('selected name', this.statusdata.filter(v => v.groupid == this.registerForm.get('title').value)[0].groupname);

     }
    }

app.component.html
-----------------
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happenss :)
</p>
<div>
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
<select formControlName="title" class="form-control">

                        <option *ngFor="let grpdata of statusdata" value="{{grpdata.groupid}}">{{grpdata.groupname}}</option>

                    </select>
 </form>
</div>
<p>home works!</p>
<div><span (click)="getSelectedVal()">Click here</span></div>
```

Comment: how do you get the dynamic value, would this be passed via the url? how do you know what value to pre-select?

Comment: No I need to pass as integer like new FormControl(1),now I am passing 1 as hardcoded integer.Just remove first object{"groupid":1,"groupname":"project1"}, from json array and check , I just need to resolve that error  or it should be work with any number of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the form to using `patchValue` method to select the first group in `statusdata` array. This way you don't have to hard-code anything.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggnhzq

(I've added a null condition for retrieving `groupname` in case there are 0 groups)